# Calendar.Month in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-calendar

I am try to set an alarm to trigger a service every 12 months.

so I tried the following:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 12);
Log.e("calendar", "= " + Calendar.MONTH + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 10);

long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext,
AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sdl, pendingIntent);
```

The above is not triggering every 12 months, I tried every 10 months it triggered? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to be triggered every twelve month then add a year to Calendar instance. Something like this -

```
calendar.add(calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

Also, if you really want to stick with adding months this is the solution -

```
calendar.add(calendar.MONTH, 12);
```

**Note -** I am using `add()` not `set()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great. Thanks.. It worked but don't see why they don't work for + 12.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer, if it had solved the issue.